# Punctuation in what I believe is a subordinate conjugation

Tags: punctuation

I have the following sentence (it's from a comment in computer code, just ignore the weird bits):

> By strong convention when opening a `typeOfObject` in the view, send in
>   an object like this `{blah blah}`.

I think there's a comma missing after "convention", but I'm not sure what the English rules for punctuation is in this case. In Swedish, there would have most definitely been a comma there, so maybe I'm just letting that influence me too much?

EDIT: I guess there should maybe also be a colon after "this", or can that be left out?

Comment: Punctuation is a matter of style, not grammar or usage. Here there's a slight semantic issue that no one will care about, mostly because no one will read program comments. Without the comma, the convention is restricted to the opening of a *typeOfObject*; with the comma, the convention might apply more broadly. There's a slight ambiguity in *like this*. You mean to refer to the *blah* code segment, but a reader might understand the reference to be to *an object*.  Use *as follows:* instead of "like this".

Comment: ... And you need at least a colon after _as follows_.

Comment: Well, it's a comment that will be parsed to documentation, and that will be read by the teams building widgets for the application. But sure, I'm not asking because people might misunderstand, I'm asking because I'm a stickler for grammar and can't quite let go until I find out the "right way" to do it :)

Comment: According to [The Punctuation Guide](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/comma.html#complexsentences), it seems the comma is in the right place in the original quote. "When a sentence begins with two dependent clauses that both apply to the subsequent independent clause, insert only a single comma after the second dependent clause. *'If you eat a balanced diet and exercise for a few hours each day, you will feel healthier.'*"

Comment: You need a comma to show that everything after the word convention is by convention.  Everything starting with 'when' is by convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence has two elements in question: a relative clause and a prepositional phrase.

The words

> when opening a `typeOfObject` in this view

form a relative clause. It is introduced by the relative adverb "when" and contains the verb "opening."

An introductory relative clause should be separated from the main clause by a comma when it is not essential to the meaning of the sentence. In this case,

> Send in an object like this

can be understood completely; the introductory relative clause just adds additional background information. ([Grammar Bytes!](http://chompchomp.com/terms/relativeclause.htm))

In contrast, the words

> By strong convention

form a prepositional phrase. It is introduced by the preposition "by" and contains the object of the preposition "convention."

[Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/03/) suggests that introductory prepositional phrases should only be followed by a comma if they are long (more than five words) or part of a series of prepositional phrases (e.g. "*On the windowsill in my bedroom*, I placed a terrarium.").

Therefore, you should retain the comma after "view" but do not need another comma after "convention."

Since this answer is long enough as-is, I will leave it to another user to advise you on the "like this" and colon question.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I will let the bounty be open for a while before awarding it to anyone, but this answer certainly qualifies.

Answer (score 0):

According to [The Punctuation Guide](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/comma.html#complexsentences), it seems the comma is in the right place in the original quote.

> When a sentence begins with two dependent clauses that both apply to the subsequent independent clause, insert only a single comma after the second dependent clause.
>
> > If you eat a balanced diet and exercise for a few hours each day, you will feel healthier.

Comment: This is the closest I've come to an answer so far. I'll add a bounty in the hope of getting a more definitive answer though.